# When using tinyMCE, is there a way to get a reference to the toolbar from an editor's instance?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using tinymce, inline mode, and in certain cases I need the ability to show/hide the toolbar of the active editor using javascript.
It should be something like:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getToolbar() // getToolbar doesn't exist
```

Only that given an editor instance, I couldn't find any way to get a reference to its toolbar.

Also note that there might be several toolbars on the page, but only one is displayed at any given time.

The toolbar is initialized like this:

```
     tinymce.init({
                selector: "#" + id,

                menubar: false,
                inline: true,
                theme: "modern",
                oninit: "setPlainText"
                ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is 3 years old. Anyway did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [discussion about this on the TinyMCE forum](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=31767). It suggests:

```
...
    setup: function (theEditor) {
        theEditor.on('focus', function () {
            $(this.contentAreaContainer.parentElement).find("div.mce-toolbar-grp").show();
        });
        theEditor.on('blur', function () {
            $(this.contentAreaContainer.parentElement).find("div.mce-toolbar-grp").hide();
        });
        theEditor.on("init", function() {
            $(this.contentAreaContainer.parentElement).find("div.mce-toolbar-grp").hide();
        });
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this already - _this_ doesn't have a property named _contentAreaContainer_. Maybe it's not defined  in inline mode. @Cymen

Comment: @Yair Ah! I'll leave my answer just in case someone comes along and isn't using inline mode. That is unfortunate though :(.